# Issue faced during the storage of the parsed JSON in the database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have parsed my JSON information and now I am trying to store it in a mysql database.

When I declare the variable as shown below:

```
$avatar = "test";
```

Then everything is stored in my database.

But when I made changes to the code as below:

```
$json_string = 'https://api.ubbo.no/api/player/'.$username.'';  
$jsondata    = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj         = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$avatarfetch = $obj['figure'];
$avatar      = "<img src='https://www.habbo.fr/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=figure=".$avatarfetch."'>";
```

When I try to insert it by pressing the submit button into the database then nothing is inserted.

What is being missed here?

Comment: show your database code.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, rank, avatar, posts) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$rank', '$avatar', '$posts')";

Comment: Read this, it will fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I dont understand it, can you please explain it easier and also give me a solution?

Comment: Your database insert code (and most likely all your db code) is open to SQL injections, it broke because of the `'` in the html string your trying to insert. Fixing injections would also fix the problem you having. That link explains it all.

Comment: Yes, fixed it my using mysqli_real_escape_string !

Comment: Use php pdo to avoid injection issues.

Comment: Have you tried checking for [`mysqli_error`s](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)?